# get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID ) does not show all children

Tags: wordpress

I am pretty new to wordpress, and wondering if someone could shed some light on this code. 
I am trying to list all sub pages on their parent page, here is the code with some html stripped out:

```
<?php
$mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID ) );

foreach( $mypages as $page ) {      
    $content = $page->post_content;
    if ( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
        continue;

    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
?>

<p style="color: white; text-transform: uppercase;"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></p>

<?php
   }   
?>
```

The code works, and correct sub pages are displayed - but not all of them. The 7 oldest posts are showing, but none of the newest pages that I created this week. I have checked and double checked that all new and old pages are the same in every way - same template, same parent page, same creator, same order number, and all published. Anyone have an idea of what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Do all of them have content?

Comment: yes - all of their content also follows the same layout and they all have roughly the same amount of content

Comment: Have you tried using the parent parameter rather than the child of parameter?  Any change in results?

Comment: I changed 
get_pages(array('child_of' => $post->ID ) 
to 
get_pages(array('parent' => $post->ID )
and got the same result unfortunately. Is this what you were talking about?

Comment: Yes that is what I was referring to.  Maybe the hierarchical flag setting in my answer below will help!

Comment: Thanks alot @tjfo, your comments lead me to understand the hierarchical setting and issues with using 'child_of' with 'number", but unfortunately I haven't gotten it working yet. I notice though, that the pages not displaying were created on a new theme, and the pages that are showing were all created on the old theme - could the different theme have caused this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
$args = array('child_of' => $post->ID,'sort_order' => 'desc',
'sort_column' => 'ID',
);
```

Comment: It looks like you can't use number with child_of according to the docs: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

Comment: i have updated my answer, nyway i have tried with number and it is working too :)

Comment: Thanks guys, this answer and subsequent comments got me a lot closer to understanding the issue

Answer (score 1):

I think you need additional argument as well to get result you are looking for.

```
$args = array( 
        'child_of' => $post->ID, 
        'parent ' => $post->ID,
        'hierarchical' => 0,
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 
        'sort_order' => 'asc'
);
$mypages = get_pages( $args );
```

You can check wordpress [Doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) for its argument and return output.

**NOTE** If you want to sort pages by date then you can change `'sort_column' => 'menu_order',` with `'sort_column' => 'post_date',`.

There is other method as well to achieve the same and I prefer below way.

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
 );

$mypages = new WP_Query( $args );


if ( $mypages->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( $mypages->have_posts() ) : $mypages->the_post(); ?>

        <p style="color: white; text-transform: uppercase;"><?php the_title(); ?></p>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

You can also use [wp_list_pages](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/) to render direct HTML.

Comment: rohil she want to display latest post.:)

Comment: @AshPatel Badhu aapne thodi kari ne aapva nu hoy :)

Comment: @AshPatel :D :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using parent instead of child_of and setting hierarchical to false.  According to the docs it appears the default hierarchical value of true can can affect the results.

```
<?php
    $mypages = get_pages( array( 'parent' => $post->ID,  'hierarchical' => 0  ) );
?>
```

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue, but I actually have no idea why this works. Any comments about why this did the trick would be awesome.

From my original code, I removed the "if ( ! $content )" section, and they all show up - even though all pages have the same amount of content.

So, in the end, my code reads:

```
<?php
$mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID ) );

foreach( $mypages as $page ) {      
$content = $page->post_content;
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
?>

<p style="color: white; text-transform: uppercase;"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></p>

<?php
}   
?>
```

I never had to change the get_pages function parameters at all.

Comment: I am using Advanced Custom Fields for the content on the new pages that weren't displaying at first - the pages that were showing must all have old content. I think wordpress was finding that content, but not the content stored in ACF?

Comment: Your condition was for `content = $page->post_content;`. So if Body/Editor will have content in it, condition will be true. If you have made fields using ACF and added values in that field during page creation, but you did not add content, then your condition will be false. It is as simple as that.